# Group request pre-approval questionnaire pop up

Tags: facebook-groups

I have applied to groups that automatically generated a popup mini-questionnaire to verify the applicant meets the criteria for membership.  I would like to know how to set that up for my group.

Example:  I have a group called "Eagle Scouts of Texas."  When someone wants to join the group I would like a pop up to ask questions like "Are you an Eagle Scout?"  "What year did you earn Eagle Scout?"  "Do you live in Texas?"

That sort of thing.  How do you set that up?

Answer (score 1):

This is a beta feature that Facebook is applying on some groups. I manage more than 30 groups, of different sizes, and only one has received this feature. It's not even the largest, or the oldest, just randomly it appeared on this group and not in the others. I'm not sure Facebook will extend this feature to all groups.